# Tool to backup Stumbleupon favourites?

Tags: stumbleupon

Preferably a tool, but scripts/hacks/ideas welcome.

Update: Automatically backing up bookmarks as I click thumbs up is a good idea, but how do I backup all of my favourites prior to enabling bookmark saving?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the bookmarks that SU creates when you click thumbs-up, then it's just a matter of finding a tool to automatically backup the bookmarks. See http://www.foxmarks.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Firefox StumbleUpon add-on, you can save your favorites and tags to a Firefox bookmarks folder.

Access the toolbar options via **Toolbar: Tools > Toolbar Options > Search & Tagging**. Check the option to *Save favorites & tags to a Firefox bookmark folder*.

[image: Search & Tagging tab of StumbleUpon Toolbar Options, with option highlighted.]